# Storage (EBS) attached to my EC2 instance reporting files on two devices at once

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have on EC2 instance with two attached EBS drives.

One drive /dev/sda1 is mounted on / 
The second /dev/sda2 is mounted on /var2

So here's what's strange. Whenever I add any files to /var2 the it is also reporting that the / device is also filling up. As if they are the same device.

It's so strange. So if I were to save a 10 mb file to a directory on /var2. Both / and /var2 use 10 mb of space up.

Is this bizarre?

```
user@my-ip:~$ cat /proc/partitions

-major minor  #blocks  name

-   8        1    8388608 sda1
-   8        2  356485632 sda2
-   8       80   16777216 sdf
-   8        3     917504 sda3

user@my-ip:~$ mount

- /dev/sda1 on / type ext3 (rw)
- proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
- none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
- none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
- none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
- none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
- none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
- none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
- none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
- none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
- none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
- /dev/sda2 on /mnt type ext3 (rw)
- /dev/sdf on /var2 type ext4 (rw,noatime)
```

Comment: What is "the it" that is reporting, and what is its output?

Comment: What is the output of `mount`?

Comment: That could be a bind mount of 2 (or more) moint points to the same filesystem (but possibly to different directories). I, too, want to see the output of the "mount" command. And what device names did you mount the TWO attached EBS volumes to? Also show output of "cat /proc/partitions".

Comment: Hey guys. Here is what I'm seeing
cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name
   8        1    8388608 sda1
   8        2  356485632 sda2
   8       80   16777216 sdf
   8        3     917504 sda3